# Expand space between values on x axis using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to expand the space between the periods on the x-axis so that the years are not overlapping

```
ggplot(LEcont, aes(Date, Value, color = Country, group = Country)) + 
  geom_line()+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(colour="Continents")+
  labs(x="Period")+
  labs(y="Life expectancy in years")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have you tried just resizing the plot to make it wider?

Comment: Just FYI you can give `labs` many arguments, `labs(colour="Continents", x="Period", y="Life expectancy in years")`, you don't need a new `+ labs()` every time.

Comment: @MrFlick how would you resize the plot? I am not sure how to do that.
Is it also possible just to display every third period on the x-axis?